# Plotting Geospatial Visualization in Python

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, geospatial, coordinate-systems

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| salesperson | company | sales_amount | area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | AA | 54000 | bandung |
| def | BB | 23000 | bogor |
| ghi | BC | 54000 | bandung |
| jkl | DE | 23000 | bogor |
| abc | IJ | 54000 | bandung |
| ghi | KL | 23000 | bogor |

I want to visualize the number of `company` data above based on the area per `salesperson`. The thing is, I don't have the data of area coordinate.

This is the data output that I want to plot in a map:

```
salesperson  area
abc          bandung    2
def          bogor      1
ghi          bandung    1
ghi          bogor      1
jkl          bogor      1
```

Is it possible to plot a geospatial visualization without the coordinate data? Or should I look for the area coordinate data to plot a geospatial visualization?

Comment: You need external co-ordinates, try mapping with something like https://data.humdata.org/dataset/cod-ab-idn, or https://simplemaps.com/data/id-cities

Comment: thank you! I'll take a look at those references

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the coordinates of these places, so do first the following to append that data to you dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

data = {
    'salesperson': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'abc', 'ghi'],
    'company': ['AA', 'BB', 'BC', 'DE', 'IJ', 'KL'],
    'sales_amount': [54000, 23000, 54000, 23000, 54000, 23000],
    'area': ['bandung', 'bogor', 'bandung', 'bogor', 'bandung', 'bogor']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='my_application')

def get_lat_lon(location):
    try:
        # Use the geolocator to obtain the location information
        loc = geolocator.geocode(location)
        # Extract the latitude and longitude
        lat, lon = loc.latitude, loc.longitude
        return lat, lon
    except:
        return None, None

df['latitude'], df['longitude'] = zip(*df['area'].apply(get_lat_lon))

## If you get a set copy warning, replace the above line by
#df['latitude'] = None
#df['longitude'] = None
#for index, row in df.iterrows():
#    lat, lon = get_lat_lon(row['area'])
#    df.loc[index, 'latitude'] = lat
#    df.loc[index, 'longitude'] = lon


# Print the dataframe with latitude and longitude columns
print(df)
```

which returns:

```
  salesperson company  sales_amount     area  latitude   longitude
0         abc      AA         54000  bandung -6.934469  107.604954
1         def      BB         23000    bogor -6.596299  106.797242
2         ghi      BC         54000  bandung -6.934469  107.604954
3         jkl      DE         23000    bogor -6.596299  106.797242
4         abc      IJ         54000  bandung -6.934469  107.604954
5         ghi      KL         23000    bogor -6.596299  106.797242
```

and then map:

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster

center = [-6.1754, 106.8272]  # Jakarta, Indonesia

map_sales = folium.Map(location=center, zoom_start=8)

marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(map_sales)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    lat, lon = row['latitude'], row['longitude']
    # Create a popup with the salesperson and the number of companies in the area
    popup_text = f"Salesperson: {row['salesperson']}<br>Number of companies: {row['area']}<br>Sales amount: {row['sales_amount']}"
    folium.Marker(location=[lat, lon], popup=popup_text).add_to(marker_cluster)
    folium.CircleMarker(location=[lat, lon], radius=row['sales_amount']/10000,
                        fill_color='red', color=None, fill_opacity=0.2).add_to(map_sales)

map_sales
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer. when I tried to implement the code, it returned this error:

`SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: @rainydays. It is a Warning and th code should run anyhow. I have added a few lines that you can unmark to replace ```df['latitude'], df['longitude'] = zip(*df['area'].apply(get_lat_lon))``` because I suspect it is where this occurs.

Comment: hi again, I've just run the code and it works perfectly, thank u so much, but some same areas return 'None' latitude and longitude, while the others return the right latitude and longitude. I tried to compare the string values within these same areas and they appear all the same (no differences in the string structure). do you by any chance know what is wrong?

Comment: In those cases it might be so that Nominatim does not find these locations. Check spelling.